# Trouble adding video as background

Tags: html, css, video, background

i've looked around online and have tried two different methods, however, both don't seem to be working.

I need to make a video cover a whole webpage background (i've done it like so) -

css -

```
video#bgvid {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    background: url(polina.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

HTML -

```
  <video playsinline autoplay muted loop poster="img/videoframe.jpg" id="bgvid">
        <source src="https://streamable.com/kuuap9" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
```

This however doesn't load anything onto my website background... am i missing something here / is there a simpler solution?

another way i tried is, with no luck is -

CSS-

```
.fullscreen-bg {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -100;
}

.fullscreen-bg__video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

HTML-

```
<div class="fullscreen-bg">
    <video playsinline autoplay muted loop poster="img/videoframe.jpg" id="bgvid">
        <source src="https://streamable.com/kuuap9" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance guys, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The URL you have leads to a HTML page. The actual url of the `.mp4` file is considerably different - like `https://cdn-cf-east.streamable.com/video/mp4/kuuap9.mp4?Expires=1627458780&Signature=bpOPaCkLp3HFo1EOHPTyexGSbohPdY5z7souBB9CzNBtF30ctrnGiQTrP5GLBbwIRjc5e94zZfChFoeSBqB-SGzh3wQAau0neacZbaKeDgDQtL1BLKy79f3qYOawIk3Mij9ZaUWV9QvzxiwoQTCtTIu2Am3RECxge68Yqc4gqRKajElNLbXZ7eeBK3Zznm8lqhkvuQ8Lu2FEWTrwu-BeI680Sb~05eu7Opf9sJQwU05dOHs3c2B46UgaCidBFyWkGCGH8JCULZkTNZokSAIHrTDfjzqNt7cussV775HBAJadN1ppa4-8fUhzm9htB0JkLgzcQ3GAboZQa75B9D8BoA__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIEYUVEN4EVB2OKEQ`

Comment: This is interesting, i had a feeling the source was off as all the examples i saw had a different format..

How do i retrieve this url? is it the embed link on the upload?

Comment: Not easily - you need, from the url, at least to have the `key-Pair` parameter and the url does not have the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` ( ie: no CORS ) You can however paste that link into browser and save the MP4 file

Comment: thanks a lot! Would i then just input the source as the file name.mp4? would that be retrievable through the website? :/ i thought it had to be a kind of url!

Comment: If you want to use streamable you probably need to learn more about how to embed a video from there. Whether you are allowed to use the raw mp4 (without their embedding system) I don't know, you'd need to investigate.

Comment: I ended up solving the issue thanks to everyones help here ! :) thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

just you need download file or url has .mp4

and

```
#bgvid {
         width:100%;
         hight:100vh;
         position: absulote;
         z-index:-1;


}
```

Comment: if i download the file, how do i get the mp4 to be read through the code, does it not have to be hosted somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Update your HTML with the following Code

```
<video controls playsinline autoplay muted loop poster="img/videoframe.jpg" id="bgvid">
    <source src="https://streamable.com/kuuap9" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```